# Why is $\langle x,T^*g\rangle=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

After asking the question [Understanding $\overline{Im\: }A=\bigcap_{A'f=0}\ker f$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782410/understanding-overlineim-a-bigcap-af-0-ker-f-proof).

I discovered the following theorem in a book which made me realize where my doubt lies more specifically:

> Theorem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $T\in L(X,Y)$. Then $\ker T^*=\operatorname{Im} \:T$

Proof:
\begin{align*}\ker T^*&=\{g\in Y^*:T^*g=0\}\\ &=\{g\in Y^*:\langle x,T^*g\rangle=0,\forall x\in X\}\\&=\{g\in Y^*:\langle Tx,g\rangle=0,\forall x\in X\}\\&=\operatorname{Im}\:T.\end{align*}

**Question**:

Why is $\langle x,T^*g\rangle=0?$ Does that not imply that the image of the adjoint operator is always $0?$ I am not understanding the argument here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both the theorem and the proof are clearly wrong. In general, $\ker T^\ast$ and $\operatorname{im} T$ are not even subspaces of the same space, so your claimed identity does not make sense at all. A correct version would be $\ker T^\ast=(\operatorname{im}T)^\perp$.

Comment: @MaoWao What do you think of the other version. The one I provided the link to.

Comment: That should be just what I wrote in my comment, and I think it has been answered many times before, for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775353/range-and-kernel-of-linear-operators or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611697/let-e-and-f-are-banach-spaces-and-a-da-subset-e-to-fbe-closed-and-den/1611914#1611914

Comment: @MaoWao              Thanks for the replies! I was told by my professor that this is right $\overline{Im\: }A=\{y\in Y:f(y)=0,\forall f\in Y'$ such that $A'f=0\}$. This goes against my intuition and against what you say. Is the Professor wrong? This would imply that $f(Ax)=0,\forall x$.

Comment: No, your professor is right and this is exactly what is proven in the linked answers. It is just not what you wrote in your question.

Comment: @MaoWao               I finally got it. I was misinterpreting it. Thanks!